# DevExpress GridViewDataComboBoxColumn displaying value(id) instead of text in display mode

Tags: devexpress

I am using a DevExpress `ASPxGridView` containing column `GridViewDataComboBoxColumn`.

The combo box is working correctly in edit mode (allows AJAX style filtering; it inserts, updates and deletes correctly).

The only problem is that in display mode it is displaying the `ValueField` (numeric id) instead of the `TextField`.

```
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Width="200px" FieldName="LocationKeyUid" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Index">
<PropertiesComboBox EnableCallbackMode="true" CallbackPageSize="7" IncrementalFilteringMode="StartsWith"
OnItemsRequestedByFilterCondition="ItemsRequestedByFilterCondition" OnItemRequestedByValue="ItemsRequestedByValue"
TextField="KeyValue" ValueType="System.Int32" TextFormatString="({0}) {1}" ValueField="LocationKeyUid" />
```

As shown above, I've tried different experiments with setting the `TextFormatString`, but that seems to be ignored.

I am binding as follows:

```
IList<LocationKeyGridViewModel> locationKeys = GetLocationKeys();
locationKeyGridView.DataSource = locationKeys;
locationKeyGridView.DataBind();
```

The class property names (below) are assigned to the `TextField` and `ValueField` property settings (above).

```
public class LocationKeyGridViewModel
{
    public int LocationKeyUid { get; set; }
    public string KeyValue { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried changing the `FieldName` property assignment to the `TextField` assignment
(i.e. `KeyValue`) but that generates an `Input string is not in correct format` error.

Is there something obvious here that I am missing?

Comment: Where do you bind grid - in what grid event? Can you post your ItemsRequestedByValue method?

Comment: I was binding on the Page_Load event (where PostBack is true). I also (just now) changed it to the OnLoad event of the AspxGridView itself--no change in behaviour. The ItemsRequestedByValue method is empty, as the user behaviour is only to search via the filter (a text value) through the ItemsRequestedByFilterCondition event. That event (which passes e.Filter to a repository query method) is working correctly, providing AJAX-style text filtering for each additional character entered.

Comment: Found a reference to this issue here: [DevExpress Issue #Q345499](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q345499.aspx)